# Is it possible to break 1 line of code into multiple in atom IDE, just like in Rstudio

Tags: julia, rstudio, atom-editor

I am new to using Julia and the atom IDE, and I was wondering if it was possible to somehow just press enter and have the computer run 1 line of code spread over multiple lines, and still have it recognize that it is still the same 1 line of code, just like in Rstudio? (I want this for readability purposes only)

what I mean is something like:

```
println("Hello 
world")
```

and be able to highlight and run this script without receiving an error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The method differs based on what the line of code contains, or specifically, where you want to break the line.

For a string like you've posted in the question, you have to precede the newline with a `\` character, to inform Julia that you're using this newline only for readability, and don't want it to be included in the actual string. (Note: I'll be illustrating these with the command-line REPL that has the `julia>`  prompt, but the same principles apply in the Atom/VS Code based IDE setups too).

```
julia> println("Hello \
       world")
Hello world
```

Outside of strings, if the current line isn't complete, Julia automatically looks for the continuation in the next line. This means that to break a line into multiple ones, you have to leave all but the final line incomplete:

```
julia> 1 + 
       2 + 
       3 * 
       4
15

julia> DEPOT_PATH |>
       first |> 
       readdir
16-element Vector{String}:
 "artifacts"
 "bin"
  ⋮

julia> 1,
       2,
       3
(1, 2, 3)
```

In some cases when you don't have a convenient binary operator to leave hanging like the above, you may have to start your line with an opening parenthesis, so that Julia will know that it's a continuous statement until the closing parenthesis is encountered.

Answer (score 2):

You also have multi-line `String`s denoted by `"""`:

```
julia> println("""This
       is
       a multi-line \
       text""")
This
is
a multi-line text
```

Comment: Yes, and the two big advantages of [triple-quoted strings](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/strings/#Triple-Quoted-String-Literals) are that you can include normal double quotes inside them without backslash escapes, and you can align the lines properly without extraneous space at the beginning. Here, if you aligned the `is` and further lines to match with the beginning of `This`, those initial spaces would be ignored so you can have both properly aligned code and properly aligned output (which wouldn't be as easy with ordinary double quoted strings).